# Windows batch copy to sort folders into folders based on partial name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory full of folders beginning with 5-digit numbers:

```
\12611_Ants
\12866_Boats
\13898_Cats
\13898B_Misbehaving_Cats
```

I would like a batch script which will create (if necessary) folders in order to sort these folders in groups of 100, so in this example, \12600, \12800, and \13800 would be created, and:

```
\12611_Ants -> \12600
\12866_Boats -> \12800
\13898_Cats -> \13800
\13898B_Misbehaving_Cats -> \13800
```

Leaving me with:

```
\12600
\12800
\13800
```

At a later date, I may then have:

```
\12600
\12800
\13800
\12825_Bats
\14055_Pangolins
```

And I would want it to leave \12600, \12800, and \13800 alone, sorting only the \12825_Bats and \14055_Pangolins folders:

```
\12825_Bats -> \12800
\14055_Pangolins -> \14000
```

I am getting hung up on selecting the correct sorting folder based on the five digit number.

Comment: Always five digits? See `set /?` for how to perform substring extraction.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Where is the code you need help with??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not usually post answers to off topic code requests, but there are too many individual parts to try to explain or link within the comment section. Here therefore is a quick example to assist you, which I will not be explaining further.

It uses the `dir` command to get your directory names which include an underscore, and the `findstr` utility to confirm that their names begin with exactly five numbers. Once it has the information it needs it uses the Robocopy utility to move the directories into their respective sorted parents.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If /I Not "%__CD__%" == "%~dp0" CD /D "%~dp0"
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir *_* /B /A:D
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][^0123456789]*_"
 ') Do (Set "DName=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%%G" "!DName:~0,3!00\%%G" /E /Move 1>NUL
    EndLocal)
```

The batch file should be placed in the same location as your directories.

To learn how each of the used commands work, please open a Command Prompt window, and enter the following, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after each:

- `echo /?`,
- `setlocal /?`,
- `if /?`,
- `cd /?`,
- `dir /?`,
- `findstr /?`,
- `for /?`,
- `set /?`,
- `robocopy /?`.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand Compo will not be commenting further, but I'm hoping someone here can help me better understand the EOL=? reference which has me confused. Reading the for /? and googling has not helped me grasp it, unfortunately.

Comment: The term `EOL` is a little confusing, because it actually refers to the Beginning Of Line, not the End Of Line. By default a `For /F` loop will omit any lines which begin with a semicolon `;` character, _(I'd assume as it was the standard prefix to a commented line in many legacy file types, `.ini`, `.inf`, `.sif` etc.)_. When your output consists of file or directory names, which don't begin with a drive letter, it's possible that it begins with a semicolon, _(a valid character)_.  To prevent those from being omitted, I've defined a `?` character instead, which isn't a valid character.